# How to Show Different Menus to Logged in Users in WordPress

Tags: menus, users, login, logout

how to write code for this requirement and i want to show menus only in header menu with different menus to logged users

Answer (score 1):

Create defferent menus in admin panel. Go to header.php and create condition, where you need change menus. Search wp_nav_menu() function and wrap into like this condition:

```
if(is_user_logged_in()){
    // call menu for logged users 
}else{
   // for non logged users
}
```